# Issue cross-compiling apr-1.5.2 for ARM

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling, autotools, apr

I am trying to cross compile Apache Portable Run-time library APR-1.5.2 lib for ARM platform. I am following below steps.

```
./configure --host=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu CC=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
make
```

I am not getting any error in configure and make but when i try to link it to my code i am getting linking error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

#include "apr_general.h"
#include "apr_network_io.h"
#include "apr_strings.h"

int main(){
    apr_initialize();
    std::cout<<"Welcome Program compiling  "<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When i am compiling the code using cross compiler getting error.

```
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ -o Test -I ../../../../Static_APR/apr-1.5.2/include DAS.cpp ../../../../Static_APR/apr-1.5.2/.libs/libapr-1.a -lpthread

**apr-1.5.2/.libs/libapr-1.a(start.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)**
```

Code compiles fine with g++.

```
g++ -o Test -I ../../../../Static_APR/apr-1.5.2/include DAS.cpp ../../../../Static_APR/apr-1.5.2/.libs/libapr-1.a -lpthread
```

Why APR lib didn't built for arm (cross compiler) even though i have used CC=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc

Can anyone help me with correct way to build APR for cross compilation?

Answer (score 1):

> I am following below steps.
>
> ```
> ./configure --host=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu CC=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
> make
> ```

Your `./configure` should include a `--build`. `--host` is the machine you are compiling for. Also see [How To Configure for Android?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf/2013-10/msg00002.html) on the Autoconf mailing list. Maybe something like:

```
export CPP=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-cpp
export CC=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
export CXX=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++
export LD=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-ld
export AR=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-ar
export AS=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-as
export RANLIB=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-ranlib

export CFLAGS="..."
export CXXFLAGS="..."

./configure --build=`config.guess` --host=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

The snippet above should ensure all the tools are available. You may need to add `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` with the appropriate header location; and an `LDFLAGS` with the appropriate library location.

You should verify the program for `RANLIB`. Its may not be what you think. For example, on one version of Ubuntu for ARM it is:

```
export RANLIB=aarch64-unknown-linux-gcc-ranlib-4.7
```

You may need to find `config.guess`:

```
$ find /usr -name 'config.guess'
/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/config.guess
/usr/share/automake-1.15/config.guess
...
```

Finally, you might find these scripts useful. They help build another library by setting paths and setting tools: [setenv-android.sh](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/setenv-android.sh) and [setenv-embedded.sh](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/setenv-embedded.sh).

Comment: Thanks for the information

As per my understanding and GCC documentation 
    --build is the machine you are building on
    --host is the machine you are building for
    --target is  the machine that GCC will produce binary for

Comment: @VinayPatel - My bad, sorry about that. According to [How To Configure for Android?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf/2013-10/msg00003.html) on the Autoconf mailing list, you need to use both `--host` and `--build`. `--target` is for building compilers. I'm going to change the answer.